# ffpmeg - how to detect if video crop is completed?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, ffmpeg, electron

Thanks in advance.

I'm trying to crop a `.mp4` video using an `ffmpeg` binary (within the context of an `electron-react-app`).

(The binary is run in a `child process` using `execFile()` and outputs to a temp folder which is later deleted)

`ffmpeg` varies considerably in the time it takes to complete the creation of a cropped video file (1sec to 18sec) depending on the computer (mac vs Windows).

I need to read the cropped video file.

I've set up an event listener in the `Main` process of `electron`

```
if (!monitorCroppedFile) {
        console.log(`${croppedFilePath} doesn't exist`);
      } else {
        console.log(`${croppedFilePath} exists !`)
        ...readFile...;
```

Once `monitorCroppedFile = true` I read it using `fs.readfile()`.

The problem is that `ffmpeg` initally creates the cropped file path but it sometimes takes ages to complete the process of cropping.

This results in the read file often being blank (as the read is triggered on detecting the file path of the cropped file).

I've tried using `-preset ultrafast` in the `ffmpeg` arguments but this only improves things on Windows marginally.

The problem doesn't occur on Macs.

Can anybody suggest a possible solution ? Is there a way to detect when the crop is fully completed ?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `-progress FILE` to your command where `FILE` should be a filename. ffmpeg will log processing status to that file. Search for the line `progress=end` in it. Once you find it, you can read the file.